# DataAnnotations Localization in aspnet core

Tags: asp.net-core

I have 2 projects in one solution. One of them named UICORE and another is named DomainCore. UICore is an ASPNETCORE project which has my controllers and views.
DomainCore is a classlibrary which has all of my entities classes. I am wanting to use localized DataAnnotations. I studied "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization" but I can't get it to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

If DataAnnotations for Domain and View models hits your problem(or a part of that), I suggest this method.

If not, do not downvote. It might be usefull for DataAnnotations tag.

In order to write DataAnnotations once, use abstract classes. In this example of New entity, I named the abstract class NewMetaData.

DomainCore project:

```
namespace myProject.DomainCore
{
    public class New : NewMetaData
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class NewMetaData
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "New Title is required")]
        [StringLength(maximumLength:150, ErrorMessage = "New Title length must not exceed 150 characters")]
        [Display(Name = "Title on New")]
        private string Title { get; set; }  //pay attention to privates

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "New Content is required")]
        [Display(Name = "Content of New")]
        private string Content { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Publish Date")]
        private DateTime Date { get; set; }        

    }
}
```

And the viewmodel class in UICore project must also inherit NewMetaData class:

```
namespace myProject.UICore.Models.News
{
    public class NewCreateModel: NewMetaData
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [AllowHtml]
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }

    public class NewDetailsModel :NewMetaData
    {
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

As you can see, You are able to add extra DataAnotations to you properties like AllowHtml, HiddenInput and ... inside the UICore and still keeping the base Annotations untouched.

This is the easiest Cross-Project method for Annotating your Models once and using them many times.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:
https://damienbod.com/2015/10/24/using-dataannotations-and-localization-in-asp-net-5-mvc-6/

You need to add your data annonations localizations to a shared resource and add this to each controller, view where it is used with a localized response.

Answer (score 0):

you have to configure localization in your startup file, and add DataAnnotations localization options;

```
services.AddMvc()
.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
.AddViewLocalization(o=>o.ResourcesPath = "ResourcesFolder")
.AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(o=> {
    var type = typeof(MyResource);
    var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
    var factory = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IStringLocalizerFactory>();
    var localizer = factory.Create("MyResource", assemblyName.Name);
    o.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (t, f) => localizer;
})
```

this will localize data attributes like:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage= "...")]
[StringLength(ErrorMessage= "...")]
[Range(ErrorMessage= "...")]
```

and so on..

but you still have to configure ModelBinding error messages (e.g.: checking numbers, null values,..etc)

```
services.AddMvc()
.AddMvcOptions(o =>
        {
            var type = typeof(MyResource);
            var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
            var factory = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IStringLocalizerFactory>();
            var localizer = factory.Create("MyResource", assemblyName.Name);

            o.ModelBindingMessageProvider
                .SetAttemptedValueIsInvalidAccessor((x, y) => localizer["'{0}' is not a valid value for '{1}'", x, y]);

            o.ModelBindingMessageProvider
                .SetValueMustBeANumberAccessor((x) => localizer["'{0}' must be a number.", x]);
        });
```

and if you have implemented identity system you have to localize identity error messages (duplicated email, password policies,...etc) by overriding IdentityErrorDescriber methods;

```
public class LocalizedIdentityErrorDescriber : IdentityErrorDescriber
{
    public override IdentityError DuplicateEmail(string email)
    {
        return new IdentityError
        {
            Code = nameof(DuplicateEmail),
            Description = string.Format(LocalizedIdentityErrorMessages.DuplicateEmail, email)
        };
    }

    public override IdentityError DuplicateUserName(string userName)
    {
        return new IdentityError
        {
            Code = nameof(DuplicateUserName),
            Description = string.Format(LocalizedIdentityErrorMessages.DuplicateUserName, userName)
        };
    }

    public override IdentityError InvalidEmail(string email)
    {
        return new IdentityError
        {
            Code = nameof(InvalidEmail),
            Description = string.Format(LocalizedIdentityErrorMessages.InvalidEmail, email)
        };
    }

    public override IdentityError DuplicateRoleName(string role)
    {
        return new IdentityError
        {
            Code = nameof(DuplicateRoleName),
            Description = string.Format(LocalizedIdentityErrorMessages.DuplicateRoleName, role)
        };
    }

    public override IdentityError InvalidRoleName(string role)
    {
        return new IdentityError
        {
            Code = nameof(InvalidRoleName),
            Description = string.Format(LocalizedIdentityErrorMessages.InvalidRoleName, role)
        };
    }

    public override IdentityError InvalidToken()
    {
        return new IdentityError
        {
            Code = nameof(InvalidToken),
            Description = LocalizedIdentityErrorMessages.InvalidToken
        };
    }

    public override IdentityError InvalidUserName(string userName)
    {
        return new IdentityError
        {
            Code = nameof(InvalidUserName),
            Description = string.Format(LocalizedIdentityErrorMessages.InvalidUserName, userName)
        };
    }

    public override IdentityError LoginAlreadyAssociated()
    {
        return new IdentityError
        {
            Code = nameof(LoginAlreadyAssociated),
            Description = LocalizedIdentityErrorMessages.LoginAlreadyAssociated
        };
    }

    public override IdentityError PasswordMismatch()
    {
        return new IdentityError
        {
            Code = nameof(PasswordMismatch),
            Description = LocalizedIdentityErrorMessages.PasswordMismatch
        };
    }

    public override IdentityError PasswordRequiresDigit()
    {
        return new IdentityError
        {
            Code = nameof(PasswordRequiresDigit),
            Description = LocalizedIdentityErrorMessages.PasswordRequiresDigit
        };
    }

    public override IdentityError PasswordRequiresLower()
    {
        return new IdentityError
        {
            Code = nameof(PasswordRequiresLower),
            Description = LocalizedIdentityErrorMessages.PasswordRequiresLower
        };
    }

    public override IdentityError PasswordRequiresNonAlphanumeric()
    {
        return new IdentityError
        {
            Code = nameof(PasswordRequiresNonAlphanumeric),
            Description = LocalizedIdentityErrorMessages.PasswordRequiresNonAlphanumeric
        };
    }

    public override IdentityError PasswordRequiresUniqueChars(int uniqueChars)
    {
        return new IdentityError
        {
            Code = nameof(PasswordRequiresUniqueChars),
            Description = string.Format(LocalizedIdentityErrorMessages.PasswordRequiresUniqueChars, uniqueChars)
        };
    }

    public override IdentityError PasswordRequiresUpper()
    {
        return new IdentityError
        {
            Code = nameof(PasswordRequiresUpper),
            Description = LocalizedIdentityErrorMessages.PasswordRequiresUpper
        };
    }

    public override IdentityError PasswordTooShort(int length)
    {
        return new IdentityError
        {
            Code = nameof(PasswordTooShort),
            Description = string.Format(LocalizedIdentityErrorMessages.PasswordTooShort, length)
        };
    }

    public override IdentityError UserAlreadyHasPassword()
    {
        return new IdentityError
        {
            Code = nameof(UserAlreadyHasPassword),
            Description = LocalizedIdentityErrorMessages.UserAlreadyHasPassword
        };
    }

    public override IdentityError UserAlreadyInRole(string role)
    {
        return new IdentityError
        {
            Code = nameof(UserAlreadyInRole),
            Description = string.Format(LocalizedIdentityErrorMessages.UserAlreadyInRole, role)
        };
    }

    public override IdentityError UserNotInRole(string role)
    {
        return new IdentityError
        {
            Code = nameof(UserNotInRole),
            Description = string.Format(LocalizedIdentityErrorMessages.UserNotInRole, role)
        };
    }

    public override IdentityError UserLockoutNotEnabled()
    {
        return new IdentityError
        {
            Code = nameof(UserLockoutNotEnabled),
            Description = LocalizedIdentityErrorMessages.UserLockoutNotEnabled
        };
    }

    public override IdentityError RecoveryCodeRedemptionFailed()
    {
        return new IdentityError
        {
            Code = nameof(RecoveryCodeRedemptionFailed),
            Description = LocalizedIdentityErrorMessages.RecoveryCodeRedemptionFailed
        };
    }

    public override IdentityError ConcurrencyFailure()
    {
        return new IdentityError
        {
            Code = nameof(ConcurrencyFailure),
            Description = LocalizedIdentityErrorMessages.ConcurrencyFailure
        };
    }

    public override IdentityError DefaultError()
    {
        return new IdentityError
        {
            Code = nameof(DefaultError),
            Description = LocalizedIdentityErrorMessages.DefaultIdentityError
        };
    }
}
```

in this sample all localized identity error messages are provided in resource files named LocalizedIdentityErrorMessages with public access modifiers.

you can check these articles about localization, it contains live demo and sample project on GitHub.

Developing multicultural web application:
http://www.ziyad.info/en/articles/10-Developing_Multicultural_Web_Application

Localizing data annotations:
http://www.ziyad.info/en/articles/16-Localizing_DataAnnotations

Localizing identity error messages:
http://www.ziyad.info/en/articles/20-Localizing_Identity_Error_Messages

Localizing ModelBinding error messages:
http://www.ziyad.info/en/articles/18-Localizing_ModelBinding_Error_Messages

Client side validation:
http://www.ziyad.info/en/articles/19-Client_Side_Validation